# Draft-js editors causing reversed input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I've got an application that requires multiple text inputs, and for formatting and customization I've chosen `draft-js` as my editor, however I've come across a very bewildering input issue.

When I type into the editors, my most recently pressed key is printed at the beginning of the editor, reversing my entire input, as if the caret is always at the first index of the line.

I have 3 editors, each one has an onChange, that updates a redux store with the editors current `contentState`. When the page is re-rendered, each editor is then rendered with their respective `contentState` transformed into an `EditorState`.

Here is my code:

**main.js**

```
render() {

    /* Each Editor has a similar block as below */

    let coverEditorState = EditorState.createEmpty()
    let coverContentState = _.get(data, 'details.message.cover.contentState')

    if (typeof coverContentHTML != "undefined"){
        coverEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(coverContentState)
    }

    return (
        ...
        <Composer
            editorState={coverEditorState}
            onChange={this._handleCoveringLetterChange.bind(this)}
        />
        ...
    )
}
```

**Composer.js**

```
class Composer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(), styleMap: {} }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
        this.setState({ editorState: nextProps.editorState })
    }

    onChange( editorState ) {

        let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, { editorState })

        let currentContentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()

        let changeObject = {
            contentState: currentContentState
        }

        this.setState(nextState)
        this.props.onChange(changeObject)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Editor 
                editorState={this.state.editorState}
                onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried returning the `SelectionState` as well as the `ContentState`, combining the two, and re-rendering, but that only leads to more problems and errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit (and resolved) a similar problem.

If you're having the same problem as me, it's because the call to `setState` actually queues an update to the state, and it's not being applied before the call to `this.props.onChange`. This understandably seems to throw `draft.js` out of whack.

Try changing:

```
this.setState(nextState)
this.props.onChange(changeObject)
```

to:

```
this.setState(nextState, () => { 
    this.props.onChange(changeObject); 
});
```

This will ensure the state is updated before calling the parent `onChange` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see by the code you've provided, but it sounds like your problem is that you're recreating the EditorState (using `EditorState.createEmpty()` or `EditorState.createWithContetnt()`) on each change. That won't work, since it's only restoring the content — not the cursor position, selection, etc.

The way I've solved it, is that I create the `EditorState` only **once**, i.e. if it doesn't already exist. Then, on each change, I update the `EditorState` normally **and**, at the same time, save the `contentState` to, in our case, the database. *The important thing here is that you don't use the `contentState` to create a new `EditorState`.*

So the next time the `EditorState` doesn't exist, it gets initialized using `EditorState.createWithContent(contentStateFromDB)`.